# PHPStorm is deploying files via FTP with wrong file datetime stamp

Tags: datetime, deployment, ftp, phpstorm

When I deploy files via FTP in PHPStorm they end up on the server with a file datetime stamp that is *off* by 1 hour. As a result all files appear to be out of sync when they are not.

In my deployment options I have enabled "preserve files timestamps".

I've checked that both my workstation and server have the same date timezone settings (server is running Windows Server).

I'm using FileZilla as the FTP server.

I wonder if the problem is related to daylight savings somehow, because the time is off by 1 hour.

Other than this and extensive google searches. I can not find a fix or an example of someone else having this problem.

Comment: Just ran in the same problem, unchecking preserve files timestamp solves the issue. But I wonder why it is off by 1 hour when it is checked.

Comment: @MarkVeenstra I remember digging more into this issue after posting. Appears to be a bug in the FTP protocol itself. PHPStorm is actually deploying the files correctly, but the FTP server is not converting the timestamp correctly. FileZilla has a hack in place to work around this known issue, and because of that it's timestamps are correct. That's as far as I got before I gave up on using PHPStorm for deploying.